# volume of liquid in a boiler based heating system

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

We're trying to improve energy efficiency for my dad's hothouse.
The setup includes a gas boiler and a pump running the heated water thru special pipes to heat the grow space.

My question is, leaving everything constant, can a change in total volume of liquid within the system (using smaller diameter pipes) affect the total energy consumption?

My guess is, conservation of energy would mean there is no change.
I'm in operations management myself, so don't really have any confidence here.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You say you want to improve the system efficiency. This is hard to do until you know where the efficiency-limiters are:  these would be places where heat is leaking out of the system, or where things are that prevent heat from being delivered to the system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your point, but lets assume the losses have been accounted for and are unchanged. My question is really about the natural gas bill for the boiler. If it has to heat a smaller amount of liquid more often, would that result in any savings?

Comment: no it would not. the heat transferred in either case has to be the same in order to maintain the greenhouse at the desired temperature setpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimum amount of energy that the system must consume to operate. This is the work required to displace fluid from the pump to your hothouse. Technicians that installed the system will have accounted for this, and included losses in the system.

Power consumption will be set by the pump, not the pipes. Varying pipe diameter will alter the systems total volume and reduce pressure, but the pump will still be delivering the same volume of fluid at any given time, requiring the same electrical input.

Your guess that conversation of energy, implies that there will be no change is correct. The same work will be required to displace the same amount of fluid. The only way to improve the energy consumption is to pump less fluid.

Comment: My question is regarding the boiler. It has been suggested to me that, if the system had less liquid, there would be less energy required to get to target temp, which makes sense. But I argued that the heating cycle would then have to be repeated more times, thus using more fuel, in order to get the actual hothouse up to temp. Would there be any effect of my natural gas bill?

Comment: Ultimately, the minimum energy required to heat the room to a certain temperature will always be the same. A reduction in fluid will reduce the energy required to heat the pipes, but to heat your room, the same energy will always be required.

To reduce your gas bill, you need to remove losses in the system (instead of trying to reduce the amount of heat delivered to the hothouse.)

Unfortunately physics stack exchange is not the best place to ask for that. You would be better off talking to technicians or specialists.